# CakePHP ACL use case(s)

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-1.3

I have got a simple web app in development, i want to establish a couple of user groups; Admin, Doctors & Patients.

Each group would have their access restricted to particular controller actions rather than individual content. So for example, Doctors can view patient records (index & view actions), but cannot delete them.

Usually i would create a groups model, and assign the various users to a group. And filter in the beforeFilter() method to determine if the user has access. But if ACL can do the job, why right the code, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to filter in the beforeFilter() method to determine if the user has access but you need to provide configuration to Auth component there. Follow [Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application) from tutorial ([Setting up permissions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1550/Setting-up-permissions)).

Comment: I settled on this approach http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/minimalistic-group-based-access-control-in-5-mins

Thanks for taking the time